# How do you remove and add bytes from a byte array in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am sending and receiving binary files and need to add a session number to each packet that is sent.

I have tried sending it as a completely different packet but that takes to much overhead.

How can i append and then later split the integer from the bytes?

The sender looks like this:

```
file = open(file.pdf, rb) 
while PCOUNT < PTOTAL:
    data = file.read(1024)
    data = data.(I would like to add PCOUNT to beggining of data)
    sendto(data,(host,port))
    PCOUNT += 1
file.close
```

The receiver should look like this:

```
data = recv(data)
data = data.split(somehow) #or some other method 
session_number = data[0]
binary_data = data[1]
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to stop using raw bytes and start using a protocol.

Comment: low level socket programming UDP for file transfers, I'm writing my own protocal